# Question is to find repeated elements in an array?

Tags: java, arrays

Example
N = 5

arr[] = {1,2,3,3,4}

Output: 3 2

Explanation: In the given array, 3 is
occuring two times.

```
class Solution
{
    //Function to find repeated element and its frequency.
    public static Point findRepeating(Integer arr[],int n)
    {
        //Your code here
        int slow=arr[0],fast=arr[0];int count=0;
        do
        {
            slow=arr[slow];
            fast=arr[arr[fast]];
        }
        while(slow!=fast);
        slow=arr[0];
        while(slow!=fast)
        {
            fast=arr[fast];
            slow=arr[slow];
            count++;
        }
        System.out.println(slow+" "+count);
         return new Point();
    }  
};
```

If I am applying  *"return new Point()"*,My output is coming 3 2
plus additional two zeroes after that, shown below

3 2

0 0

Comment: What is your question exactly?  The code you have in the loop along with the print statement are not related at all from what your function returns.

Comment: What's the purpose of `n`? You're never using it, so why is it a parameter here?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't mentioned what 'n' is. However, repeated elements and their frequencies can be also found this way using a Hashmap.

```
            int[] arr = {2,6,4,4,8,7,2,2,8,8,8,8};

            Map<Integer, Integer> count = new HashMap<>();

            for (Integer c : arr) {
                if (count.containsKey(c)) {
                    count.put(c, count.get(c) + 1);
                } else
                    count.put(c, 1);
            }

            count.values().removeIf(value -> value.equals(1));
            System.out.println(count);
```